# How to remove space "before" column name when importing csv data in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I use the default Pandas csv reading to import some data as followed:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data_file.csv')
```

The data frame I got is as below:

```
           Force [N]      Stress [MPa] 
0            0.000000       2.230649e-13
1            0.014117       1.071518e-01
2            0.135255       3.365490e+00
```

The data frame column I got here has spaces before the actual name (illustrated below) so that I could not use the actual column name string to access the column afterwards.

```
>>> df.columns
Index(['       Force [N]', '    Stress [MPa] '])
```

I would like to remove the space **before** the string, but keep the space within the column name string. Tried the following one but it will remove all spaces so the column name got changed as well.

```
df.columns=df.columns.str.replace(' ','');
```

Is there anyway to strip the white spaces to the left of column name when importing csv? I would like the column name to be like:

```
'Force [N]','Stress [MPa]'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To avoid post-processing the column data set `skipinitialspace=True` to [`pd.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
df = pd.read_csv('data_file.csv', skipinitialspace=True)
```

`df`:

```
   Force [N]  Stress [MPa]
0   0.000000  2.230649e-13
1   0.014117  1.071518e-01
2   0.135255  3.365490e+00
```

`df.columns`:

```
Index(['Force [N]', 'Stress [MPa]'], dtype='object')
```

`data_file.csv`

```
          Force [N],      Stress [MPa] 
          0.000000,       2.230649e-13
          0.014117,       1.071518e-01
          0.135255,      3.365490e+00
```

Comment: OP's data seem to also have a space after the column name

Answer (score 1):

[`pandas.Series.str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) to replace occurrences of [`^[ ]+|[ ]+$`](https://regex101.com/r/TEHIJB/2) (one or more spaces at the start or end of the column names) with `""` (nothing)

```py
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace("^[ ]+|[ ]+$", "", regex=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

A simpler alternative to the `replace` approach is [`rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html):

```
df = df.rename(columns=str.strip)
```

or using `inplace`:

```
df.rename(columns=str.strip, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Index.str.strip()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.str.html) (which is the Index version of  [`Series.str.strip()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html)), as follows:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()
```

**Input:**

```
print(df.columns)

Index(['       Force [N]', '    Stress [MPa] '], dtype='object')
```

**Output:**

```
print(df.columns)

Index(['Force [N]', 'Stress [MPa]'], dtype='object')
```