# Not able to extract any column from a pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am finding a strange issue after reading a csv file. I am reading the csv file and trying to extract specific columns from it. Below is the simple code --

```
inp = pd.read_csv("popularity.csv")
k = inp[['num_imgs']]
```

However, on running this I get this error --

```
  File "C:\Users\devshankhasharm\PycharmProjects\untitled5\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1374, in _validate_read_indexer
    raise KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]")
KeyError: "None of [Index(['num_imgs'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"
```

However, when I print inp.info() I can see the column named 'num_imgs'. Basically not able to extract value from any column even though they are shown as output of inp.info() method. What am I missing here?

### First few lines

```
url, timedelta, n_tokens_title, n_tokens_content, n_unique_tokens, n_non_stop_words, n_non_stop_unique_tokens, num_hrefs, num_self_hrefs, num_imgs, num_videos, average_token_length, num_keywords, data_channel_is_lifestyle, data_channel_is_entertainment, data_channel_is_bus, data_channel_is_socmed, data_channel_is_tech, data_channel_is_world, kw_min_min, kw_max_min, kw_avg_min, kw_min_max, kw_max_max, kw_avg_max, kw_min_avg, kw_max_avg, kw_avg_avg, self_reference_min_shares, self_reference_max_shares, self_reference_avg_sharess, weekday_is_monday, weekday_is_tuesday, weekday_is_wednesday, weekday_is_thursday, weekday_is_friday, weekday_is_saturday, weekday_is_sunday, is_weekend, LDA_00, LDA_01, LDA_02, LDA_03, LDA_04, global_subjectivity, global_sentiment_polarity, global_rate_positive_words, global_rate_negative_words, rate_positive_words, rate_negative_words, avg_positive_polarity, min_positive_polarity, max_positive_polarity, avg_negative_polarity, min_negative_polarity, max_negative_polarity, title_subjectivity, title_sentiment_polarity, abs_title_subjectivity, abs_title_sentiment_polarity, shares
http://mashable.com/2013/01/07/amazon-instant-video-browser/, 731.0, 12.0, 219.0, 0.663594466988, 0.999999992308, 0.815384609112, 4.0, 2.0, 1.0, 0.0, 4.6803652968, 5.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 496.0, 496.0, 496.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.500331204081, 0.378278929586, 0.0400046751006, 0.0412626477296, 0.0401225435029, 0.521617145481, 0.0925619834711, 0.0456621004566, 0.013698630137, 0.769230769231, 0.230769230769, 0.378636363636, 0.1, 0.7, -0.35, -0.6, -0.2, 0.5, -0.1875, 0.0, 0.1875, 593
http://mashable.com/2013/01/07/ap-samsung-sponsored-tweets/, 731.0, 9.0, 255.0, 0.604743080614, 0.999999993289, 0.79194630341, 3.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 4.9137254902, 4.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.799755687423, 0.0500466753998, 0.0500962518137, 0.0501006734234, 0.0500007119405, 0.341245791246, 0.148947811448, 0.043137254902, 0.0156862745098, 0.733333333333, 0.266666666667, 0.286914600551, 0.0333333333333, 0.7, -0.11875, -0.125, -0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.0, 711
http://mashable.com/2013/01/07/apple-40-billion-app-downloads/, 731.0, 9.0, 211.0, 0.575129530699, 0.999999991597, 0.66386554064, 3.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 4.39336492891, 6.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 918.0, 918.0, 918.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.217792288518, 0.033334456999, 0.0333514249339, 0.0333335358046, 0.682188293744, 0.702222222222, 0.323333333333, 0.0568720379147, 0.00947867298578, 0.857142857143, 0.142857142857, 0.495833333333, 0.1, 1.0, -0.466666666667, -0.8, -0.133333333333, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.0, 1500
http://mashable.com/2013/01/07/astronaut-notre-dame-bcs/, 731.0, 9.0, 531.0, 0.503787877834, 0.999999996904, 0.665634672862, 9.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 4.40489642185, 7.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0
```

Comment: Can you provide the input data? At least the first few lines. I would bet that your csv doesn't use commas as separator

Comment: Added first few lines, it has 60 columns

Comment: I think there is space in column names, you can check it by `print (df.columns.tolist())`

Comment: As you can see, the csv file is using comma as a seperator

Comment: There is a space after each comma reading the csv will mean there is a space proceeding each column header. Follow @jezrael 's linked duplicate or  [How to remove space “before” column name when importing csv data in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68339861/15497888) which both cover techniques on how to address the additional whitespace.